# I was unable to install Rails (from railsinstaller) on windows and got this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to install Rails form Railsinstaller for windows but this error

```
C:\Sites>gem install rake -v '10.5.0'
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rake' (= 10.5.0), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect retur
ned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify 
 failed                
  (

  https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that RubyGems 1.8.x, 2.0.x and 2.2.x have been released, you can manually update to those versions.

First, download the proper version of RubyGems for your installation (eg. if running version 1.8.28, download 1.8.30).

Note: To find the version of RubyGems you're using, please run gem --version in the command line.

You can find download links at GitHub under Releases.

Now, locate rubygems-update-X.Y.Z.gem where X.Y.Z will be the matching version for the version of RubyGems you need to update:

Running 1.8.x: download https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/releases/tag/v1.8.30

Running 2.0.x: donwload https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/releases/tag/v2.0.15

Running 2.2.x: download https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/releases/tag/v2.2.3

Please download the file in a directory that you can later point to (eg. the root of your harddrive C:)

Now, using your Command Prompt:

C:>gem install --local C:\rubygems-update-1.8.30.gem
C:>update_rubygems --no-ri --no-rdoc
After this, gem --version should report the new update version.

then after that you should be able to bundle install.
i dont own the instructions. i just found it.
Credits Here: https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

hope that works